# Swt caret causes redraw of the entire canvas

Tags: java, swt, gtk3

I have a Canvas I use for drawing. To draw on the canvas I have added

```
canvas.addPaintListener(paintEvent-> {
    // Misc drawing code here.
});
```

and then I add a caret to this canvas with

```
Caret c = new Caret(canvas,SWT.None);
c.setBounds(10, 10, 2, 12);
```

This works fine, and I can draw on the canvas at the // Misc drawing code here point.

But here comes the problem:
Each time the caret blink, it sends a paint event. This make sense, because I need to re-draw the content under the caret. But instead of just clearing the area around the caret, it clears the entire canvas. And if I look at x,y,width,height in the paintEvent, then x and y are 0, and width and height correspond to the size of the canvas.

So how do I get the caret, to only update the area it covered, instead of the entire canvas? it's kinda expensive to repaint the entire canvas each time the caret blinks.

Added:
I use eclipse to develop the app. If I set 
SWT_GTK3=0 in the run environment for my app,  the app don't redraw the background each time the cursor blinks. So it looks like an swt+gtk3 issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the `SWT.NO_BACKGROUND` style when creating your `Canvas` to stop the default clearing of the canvas on each paint.

The `GC` in the paint event should have a clipping region set to tell you the minimum area that needs to be repainted:

```
Rectange clipping = paintEvent.gc.getClipping();
```

You can use this to check which parts of the canvas need to be redrawn.

Comment: I have 2 different computers running Linux (Fedora). Setting SWT.NO_BACKGROUND works on one of them(No redrawing), but on the other computer, the exact same program keeps redrawing the entire frame each time time the cursor blinks. So I guess there is an issue with Gtk or my graphics driver. But that is a thing for an other question.